# How to automatically add to a number when a CountDownTimer is running?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to add numbers to an already existing number based on a formula when a CountDownTimer is running. The timer is working, but the number(amount) crashes the app

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView Time;
ImageButton button;
TextView amount;
TextView rate, milltime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Time = findViewById(R.id.Time);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    amount = findViewById(R.id.Amount);
    rate = findViewById(R.id.Ratenumber);
    milltime = findViewById(R.id.milltime);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("00");
                    long hour = (millisUntilFinished / 3600000) % 24;
                    long min = (millisUntilFinished / 60000) % 60;
                    long sec = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                    Time.setText(f.format(hour) + ":" + f.format(min) + ":" + f.format(sec));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Time.setText("Click to start");
                }
            }.start();

            new CountDownTimer(10000,1){
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    milltime.setText(""+millisUntilFinished /1000 + millisUntilFinished %1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    milltime.setText("Did it work?");

                }
            }.start();

            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(milltime.getText().toString());
            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(rate.getText().toString());

            int n3 = (1000 - n1) * n2;

            amount.setText(""+String.valueOf(n3));

        }
        });
    }
```

What I am trying to get, is the **amount** to increase as the timer runs based on the **rate**.

Comment: fixed the title, and removed the javascript tag. This is an Android Studio issue, as it's being done in Android Studio

Comment: Please also provide the stack trace from the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

without the xml I'm only assuming here

First of all, the calculation code is on the button click and out of the counter scope your crash might be because of the Integer parsing
where your milltime and rate could be empty and that's what making it crash due to NumberFormatException